# Interaction with user in a Javascript Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

there are 2 main functions on a website that I'm trying to build: 'Search users' and 'interact with users'

Search results display usernames, and I would like to POPUP a box similar to lighbox where the poped up users profile would display. Within it I need to have several action buttons, like block, add to favorites, and separate tab for messaging.

Can all of the above be displayed and refreshed within a javascript popup? What plugins/approach would you recommend?

Comment: jquery,colorbox, and jqueryUIDialog are all a good start

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, anything can be done inside a lightbox, because a lightbox is only a partially transparent image overlay with html content positioned above the image. What's more, there are plenty of lightbox plugins for jquery (almost too many lightbox plugins, really).

But before you proceed any further, you might want to start planning on creating a javascript disabled fallback for when you cannot display the lightbox.